# Product and Category models, need to loop through categories and link to their view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following models;

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cats
end

class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base  
    belongs_to :product     
    validates :product_id, presence: true
end
```

Each product and category has it's own view.

On the product page I have successfully displayed the categories with the following code;

```
 <ul>
   <% @product.cats.each do |c| %>
      <li><%= c.name %></li>
   <% end %>
 </ul>
```

However I wish to provide a link for each c.name to the category view (e.g. Laptops -> Laptop Category View, etc). I've been driving myself senseless butchering code together to no avail -

```
 <ul>
    <% @product.cats.each do |c| %>
      <li><%= link_to c.name, cat_path(cat) %></li>
    <% end %>
 </ul>
```

Can't find suitable answer on SO, so hoping someone could help?

Thanks

Comment: it looks like you have the correct code.  you need to tell us what the error is. add the stack trace to the question if there is an error.

Comment: Sorry, new to SO. Error I'm getting is...undefined local variable or method `cat' for #<#<Class:0x007fbddf36ddb0>:0x007fbddf623708>
...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<li><%= link_to c.name, cat_path(cat) %></li>
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
<li><%= link_to c.name, cat_path(c) %></li>
```

Comment: That's amazing - thank you (frustratingly close :-) )